# GitLab ci: Use artifacts from previous build for optional jobs?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a Jekyll website with a custom version of Netlify.
Both Jekyll and Netlify are built in their own job and then merged together in the `pages` job.

But since the custom Netlify almost never changes, I wanted to save some build resources by only rebuilding it when there are actual changes in the `netlify` folder.
I did this by using `rules` and defining `changes` as followed:

```
build-custom-netlify:
  stage: build
  image: node:16.2.0-buster
  script:
  - npm ci
  - npm run build
  cache:
    paths:
    - netlify/node_modules/
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - build
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME != "master"'
      when: never
    - changes:
      - /netlify/*

build-jekyll:
  stage: build
  image: jekyll/jekyll:4.2.0
  script:
  - jekyll build -d public --strict_front_matter
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - cp build/netlify.js public/admin
  dependencies:
  - build-custom-netlify
  - build-jekyll
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```

Now my `build-custom-netlify` job does indeed not run when there are no changes in the `netlify` folder.

However, now my `pages` job also fails, stating that it cannot find `build/netlify.js`.
I assume this is because the `build-custom-netlify` did not run this time, and it cannot get the previous version either.

So my question is, is there a way to get the `build/netlify.js` file from the previous build?
Or is there a different way of solving this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: So the output of the `build-custom-netlify` job is just the single file `netlify.js`? Maybe you could build this in a separate pipeline, and provide the latest version via GitLab pages?

Comment: @slauth It is indeed. That's an interesting idea, should work like that indeed, but not sure it's worth the trouble of splitting up the project like that.

Comment: On a second thought you could also grab the file right from the current deployed version, couldn't you?

Comment: @slauth Yea I guess I could. Though that also feels a bit dirty in a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the suggestions in your question's comments, there's a few options I can think of, though you'll have to remove `build-custom-netlify` from the `dependencies` array in your `pages` job to prevent it from failing immediately.

1. Instead of uploading the built directories as a Gitlab CI Job Artifact, upload the directory to AWS S3 (or similar) in a specific place such that the "latest" build is always in the same place. Then, in the `pages` job, retrieve the latest builds from S3. This way, even if in this current pipeline there were no changes, the latest will still be in S3 regardless of when it was created.
2. Within the `pages` job, use the Gitlab API to pull down pipelines (to get the IDs), then get all Jobs for each pipeline, then check to see if the job with name `build-custom-netlify` ran, and if so grab its ID, then pull down artifacts for that job ID.

While the second option would work, it could get pretty nasty if the `build-custom-netlify` job hasn't run in while. The first option is how I would implement it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I've accomplished this (Gitlab version 14.8.6). Use a cache with a branch specific key. Always run the first job, but only update the cache if it is empty or changes exist.

```
foo:
  stage: foo
  rules:
    - changes:
        - dir/to/check/for/changes/**/*
      variables:
        CHANGED: "1"
    - when: always
  script:
    - if [[ -d cacheDir ]]; then CACHE_EXISTS=1; fi
    - echo $CACHE_EXISTS
    - echo $CHANGED
    - if [ "$CACHE_EXISTS" != 1 ] || [ "$CHANGED" == 1 ]; then make foo; fi
  cache:
    key: foo-$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    paths:
      - cacheDir/

bar:
  stage: bar
  script:
    - make bar
  cache:
    key: foo-$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    policy: pull
    paths:
      - cacheDir/
```